# why is my css not making the text bold and red

Tags: html, css

```
<tr style="background-color:yellow">
    <td style="color:red font-weight:bold">
        SERVER1
    </td>
    <td style="color:red">
        Sampler
    </td>
    <td style="color:red">
        Offline
    </td>
    <td style="color:red">
        No
    </td>
</tr>
```

Can anyone please tell me why my text isn't bold and red? if I use 1 css style then it seems to work fine

Comment: you need a semi-colon after `red` and before `font-...`

Comment: @Lee Simple answers are answers too. :)

Comment: @Lee please post it so I can give you credit. Thanks your solution worked!!!!

Comment: lulz not necessary, glad to have helped :)

Comment: you should use class attributes and an external css file rather than style attributes

Comment: @ToniLeigh i need it inline because it's going to be sent as an HTML Body for an email message. Using external files means that I need to host them and make them available to each client that attempts to use it.

Comment: @softwareisfun fair enough, that's one of the few cases where this is acceptable (well, it's not really, but that's the fault of rubbish email clients rather than web authors) - there's plenty of other difficulties with this sort of thing also, tables being one of them!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to end your style property with a semicolon `;` if you have multiple properties.

```
<tr style="background-color:yellow;">
    <td style="color:red; font-weight:bold;">
        SERVER1
    </td>
    <td style="color:red;">
        Sampler
    </td>
    <td style="color:red;">
        Offline
    </td>
    <td style="color:red;">
        No
    </td>
</tr>
```